# Why do i get "source not found" when I change extends Activity to extends ListActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, listactivity, extends

I've got a problem with this class. This Activity will be called when I press a button. When I extend Activity to this class the programm  gets into the class, but when I extend ListActiviy and I click the button the debugger tells me in red words "source not found" and nothing else, not even something in the logcat. 
Please tell me if there is something missing in the xml-file of this activity or the manifest.

This is the class activity:

```
public class SeeAllEntriesActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_entries);

        ActivitiesObjects ao = (ActivitiesObjects)this.getApplication();
        List<Customer> listOfCostumer = ao.getListOfCustomers();

        ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_all_entries, listOfCostumer);
        ListView listViewCustomer = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewCustomer);
        listViewCustomer.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }
}
```

This is the xml of the activity:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="all entries" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewCustomer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the xml of the manifest:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application android:name="com.example.testapp.ActivitiesObjects" android:label="@string/app_name">
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="CreateActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="SeeAllEntriesActivity"></activity>
    </application>    

</manifest>
```

Thanks in advance,
alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One point I like to share regarding ListActivity.

> your layout must contain a ListView with the android:id attribute set
>   to @android:id/list
>
> For example android:id="@android:id/list"

there for your layout file will be like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="all entries" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

For setting list adapter you can use **`setListAdapter`** function

```
public class SeeAllEntriesActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_entries);

        ActivitiesObjects ao = (ActivitiesObjects)this.getApplication();
        List<Customer> listOfCostumer = ao.getListOfCustomers();

        ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_all_entries, listOfCostumer);
        // no need to fetch list view instance
        // ListView listViewCustomer = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewCustomer);
        setListAdapter(listAdapter);
    }
}
```

If you want to have instance of listview then you can call `getListView ()`

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I changed the code like you said and the activity really opens on the emulator without any error. Unfortunately he shows me an error when the list conains data, but I think this is because i have to write an adapter. But thank you, now I can focus on this problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot 2 "**.**" (dots).

Replace:

```
<activity android:name="CreateActivity"></activity>
<activity android:name="SeeAllEntriesActivity"></activity>
```

with:

```
<activity android:name=".CreateActivity"></activity>
<activity android:name=".SeeAllEntriesActivity"></activity>
```

Also, you have 2 `android:label` in your `application` tag.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, i tried this immediately but unfortunately it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Make sure all your package and activity paths and names are correct.

Comment: I am sure that they are correct because when I change the extends ListActivity to extends Activity he finds the class.