# Android App List of lists

Tags: android, list, listview, listadapter, sqlite

I was looking through the other list of lists posts and none of them seem to be helpful or usable in my situation (maybe I am just being dumb). Anyways, I am building an app that requires a login to a list where you can add an item that, if selected, will display a new empty list where items can be added.

For example, let's say you login and the first list is a list of workout lists. The list includes items with fields:

```
workout_list_name_ , 
workout_list_type, and 
workout_list_date.
```

If you select the item, it brings you to an empty list(new activity) where you can add an item with fields :

```
item_name , 
item_sets,item_reps, 
item_weight, 
item_completed(boolean value user can change if they have already completed it).
```

Here's where my problem is: I have these two ListViews both with `android:id="@+id/android:list"`. Both ListViews use a **SimpleCursorAdapter** to display and xml layout for the row I am adding. When I create the workout list and save it, it gets added to my sqlitedatabase but it is not showing up in my ListView.

**How do I change my ListView structures and adapters to display the data?** 
I would like to get rid of the

```
WorkoutList extends ListActivity
```

and make it only extend **Activity**, but I am just not sure how to implement this.

**Can you help me?**

Here is my code for the first List:

```
public class WorkoutList extends ListActivity {

Button addNewWorkout;
WorkoutDbAdapter mDbHelper;
public static final int CREATE_WORKOUT = 1;
//public static final int EDIT_WORKOUT = 2;
public static final int SET_WORKOUT = 2;
String dateCreated = null;
Calendar now = null; 
SimpleDateFormat format = null;
ListView myList;

Intent prevIntent ;
String woName,userName;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.workout_list);

    addNewWorkout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNewWorkout);
    prevIntent = getIntent();
    userName = prevIntent.getStringExtra("userName");

    // do the work for getting the current time and formatting it
    now = Calendar.getInstance();
    format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm aaa");
    dateCreated = format.format(now.getTime());

    mDbHelper = new WorkoutDbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();

    myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.workout_list);

    registerForContextMenu(myList);

    myList.setDivider(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.mainDivider));
    myList.setDividerHeight(1);

    addNewWorkout.setOnClickListener(NewWorkout);

    fillData();
}

OnClickListener NewWorkout = new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent newWorkout = new Intent();
        newWorkout.setClass(getApplicationContext(), AddWorkout.class);
        newWorkout.putExtra("dateCreated", dateCreated );
        newWorkout.putExtra("userName", userName);
        startActivityForResult(newWorkout, CREATE_WORKOUT);

    }

};
 //===============================================================================
//
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();

}



//===============================================================================
//
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    mDbHelper.open();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    mDbHelper.close();
}

//================================================================================
//
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        woName = data.getStringExtra("workoutName");

    fillData();
}

//================================================================================
//
// Fill the data for UI rebuilds
private void fillData(){
    Cursor workoutCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllWorkouts(userName);
    startManagingCursor(workoutCursor);

    String [] from = new String [] {WorkoutDbAdapter.KEY_WORKOUT_NAME,WorkoutDbAdapter.KEY_WORKOUT_CREATED_DATE ,
            WorkoutDbAdapter.KEY_WORKOUT_TYPE};

    int [] to = new int [] {R.id.dateCreatedLabel, R.id.nameLabel, R.id.typeLabel};

    SimpleCursorAdapter workouts = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.workout_row, workoutCursor, from, to);

    myList.setAdapter(workouts);


}


//===============================================================================
//
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu , View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Options");
    menu.setHeaderIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.list_item_longpress, menu);
}

//===============================================================================
//
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.menu_delete:
        final AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        AlertDialog.Builder confirmAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setTitle("Are you Sure?")
        .setMessage("This will permanently delete the workout and all subsequent exercises from your workout list. " +
                        "Are you sure you want to continue?")
        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                mDbHelper.deleteWorkout(info.id);
                fillData();
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();                
            }
        });
        confirmAlert.show();
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_cancel:
        return false;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);

}

//================================================================================

protected void onListItemClick(ListView myList, View v, int position, final long id){
    super.onListItemClick(myList, v, position, id);
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setIcon(R.drawable.edit)
    .setTitle("Update Selected Workout")
    .setMessage("Would you like to update the current Workout? Click continue to proceed.")
    .setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            final Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ExerciseList.class);
        i.putExtra(WorkoutDbAdapter.KEY_ROW_ID, id);
        i.putExtra("workoutName", woName);
        startActivityForResult(i, SET_WORKOUT);

        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();

        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}


}
```

Comment: you have to set your list id as android:id="@android:id/list" check out my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/12161230/582571

Comment: I think you missed my point. I have two activities that do this. I would like to get rid of extending the ListActivity and create different adapters so I do not have to use the id @android:id/list. I would like to be able to have two lists in my app

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found my own answer through another post. I was looking in the wrong place here is the link for a way to implement the `ListView` without `extends ListViewActivity`

[Android how to use adapter for listView without extending listActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267060/android-how-to-use-adapter-for-listview-without-extending-listactivity)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks messy and really difficult to maintain with the kind of requirement you have. 
You should use ListActivity only when the only thing on the screen is your list else don't. So first get rid of ListActivity. Here are few steps you could follow:

- Get rid of ListActivity. Make you class extend Activity.
- Main an xml layout for your activity which will contain your listview and other items you want to display. 
  Something like this will work:

  ```
  <RelativeLayout 

     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

     <ListView
         android:id="@+id/list"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />
  </RelativeLayout>
  ```
- Create a list of items(array,list,etc) for the first(home) listView. Create an adapter with these items and set this as the list adapter.
- For different items on this list create different set of empty lists(array,list, etc).
- Set on click listener of this ListView and implement its onClick method.
- In the onClick method based on the position of the items create an adapter with corresponding empty list(array,list,etc) and set it as the adapter of the current list view.
- Now add items to this list and call notifyDataSetChanged() on the list adapter for updating the  list with the current added item.